# Redirect primary domain to sub folder without affecting secondary domain using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domains:

- `gyanplease.com/gyanplease` primary domain (I have changed the document root with the help of `.htaccess`)
- `mobiledevsolutions.com` secondary domain

On the document root I have created a folder called `gyanplease` and with the help of `.htaccess` I have rewritten `gyanplease.com` to the `gyanplease` the folder. This the code for the redirection:

```
#disable https
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !gyanplease/
RewriteRule (.*) /gyanplease/$1 [L]
```

Now when I'm hosting another domain on the same server, that is `mobiledevsolutions.com`, then it's not working and gives a 404 redirection error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is only run the `/gyanplease/` rewrite for that host, like this (replacing the last two lines):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)gyanplease.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gyanplease/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gyanplease/$1 [L]
```

That way this rule will only affect `gyanplease.com`.

You can also change line 4 to this, since the capturing is not being used:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So all that would make your new rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Disable HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Rewrite gyanplease.com to /gyanplease/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)gyanplease.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gyanplease/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gyanplease/$1 [L]
```